# hiding an element by using a context menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can i hide an element on a webpage by creating a custom context menu? I want that i get an option when I right click on an element and it says hide or something like that. this should be custom context menu and should be done using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Please Check this awesome jquery plugin [**jQuery contextMenu**](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/)

[image]